# How to validate Text Box to allow Specific URI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, validation

i am developing application using Code-igniter.

I want to validate Text Box Using J Query Or JavaScript That only allowed to input following URL when user submit form.

```
http://
https://
ftp://
ftps://
file://
market://
linkedin://
fb://
geo:
maps://
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: plain JS is enough, use regex to accept only urls starting with that. If it's a form sounds like <input type="text" onfocusout="myFunction()">  would be a nice event binding for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_url(str)
{
    regexp =  /^(?:(?:https?|ftps?|file?|market?|linkedin?|fb?|maps?):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
    if (regexp.test(str))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For answer.But its not allwed me to enter all url like https://192.168.0.1 like geo: location url.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex in a function that checks validity of your input.

```
/^(http|https|ftp|ftps|file|market|linkedin|fb|maps|geo):\/\//g
```

But do the reverse logic:

- if it matches then display error mesage and clear input.
- If it not matches then your URL is fine

If you wanna prevent URLs anywhere in your input, remove the leading `^` in regex to match even if URL is not start of the string.

like: `/(http|https|ftp|ftps|file|market|linkedin|fb|maps|geo):\/\//gm`

Here is a crud version of entire solution:
[fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/gt24p02v/4/)

Main thing is URL validation:

```
$("#urlInput").focusout(function (){
  var inputElement = $("#urlInput");
    var regexp = /(http|https|ftp|ftps|file|market|linkedin|fb|maps|geo):\/\//gm; 
  if (regexp.test(inputElement.val())){
    inputElement.val("");
    alert("This is nto a valid URL")
  }
});
```

It bound to the

```
<input id="urlInput" type="url">
```

You might wanna rework the error reporting in a more user friendly manner but that's another story.

Comment: Like This:  var regexp = /(http|https|ftp|ftps|file|market|linkedin|fb|maps|geo):\/\//gm;
        
        var redirectUrl = $('#redirect_profile_url').val();

        if(redirectUrl != ''){
            if(regexp.test(redirectUrl)){
                msg += "Please Enter Valid Redirect Url \n";
            }
        }

Comment: Put togather a small fiddlejs for you. v4 is the correct one I fatfingered something in v2 before saving :)

Comment: Hello sir i want to validate URL i have checked your code on Fiddles but if i enter valid URL then its say not valid i want to allow user to enter valid URL